# Which is the best data structure of time for lots of Strings?

Tags: java

In class of Data Structures and Algorithms the teacher send us an assignment in which we have to take files with thousand or more name of actors and films (he took that files from imdb). And then we have to load the data from the files into the memory, search an actor, add an actor, return the movies, the actors...

```
Mostue, Trude ### Skal vi danse
Roede, Jeanette ### Skal vi danse
Rygel, Cecilie Brink ### Skal vi danse
Schanke, Guri ### Skal vi danse
Solberg, Guri ### Skal vi danse ### Absolutt underholdning ### Nettopp n 
Agdestein, Simen ### Skal vi danse ### The Shit
Brattlie, Mats ### Skal vi danse
Fl�ysvik, Tor M. ### Skal vi danse
Fransson, Jan-Eric ### Skal vi danse
Grinaker, Asmund G.S. ### Skal vi danse
Gundersen, Geir ### Skal vi danse
Hansen, Tom Arild ### Skal vi danse
Harr, Trond ### Skal vi danse
Haug, Tom A. ### Skal vi danse ### Hjem
Holthe, Bj�rn Wettre ### Skal vi danse
Kagnes, Thomas ### Skal vi danse
Lundin, Gustaf ### Skal vi danse
Newth, Eirik ### Skal vi danse
Nilsen, Tom-Erik ### Skal vi danse
Robsahm, Otto ### Skal vi danse
```

And most of the class is going to use an Arraylist, but I want to experiment and try others things and I was searching a little but I dont know exactly what data structure use or investigate, is a tree recomended?I saw another question in which someone mention the treeset but I dont know if is the best option (neither how to use it xD but I suppose I will discover that when I try to do something)
I read about hashset, hashmap and concurrenthashmap but I only used hashset and I read that is almost the same.

Answer: Our teacher told us about using Treemap, TreeSet, Hashmap, Hashset, and I dont think is duplicate, at least with that question Jarrod say because in that question the only answer is using a database and in class of algorithms and data structures is logic to use data structures to practice. Thanks for the rest of the tips, Ill try not to do that errors again.

Comment: Links can become outdated. Please include the relevant text in your question. You can still keep a link for more information, but the question should be self-contained.

Comment: How about Map<String, List<String>> and then search keys for actors' names.

Comment: it depends on what the search criteria is

Comment: Which data structure you use depends on what you are trying to do. For example, unless you want duplicates, a `Set` may be a better choice than a `List`

Comment: in the future if your question title requires the word *best* it is probably off topic in multiple ways, namely **opinion based** as well. Because *best* is not quantifiable in most cases. Best for *what*? Time, Space, Money?

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be that you would implement SQLlite, load up the data, put it in the SQL database and then you can simply query the database.
That way you get hte most flexibility and you can get the data out the fastest and with the most relations interlinking them, making for easy queries.

You can just opt for a memory only database, that way you get most speed. But if you write it to disk you get a nice compound database which can hold data from multiple files etc..

Because in essence, whatever relation you are going to set up, it will all boil down to mimicing a database, so why not reuse the wheel that was already invented, and you might get bonus points for thinking outside the box.